# PDO result and Twig template library

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I'm currently building an app using the Twig templating library.

With my PDO statement I receive the following array:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [artist] => Dena
                [track] => Cash, Diamond Ring, Swimming Pools
                [link] => http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r4CDc9yCAqE
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [artist] => Jessy Lanza
                [track] => Kathy Lee
                [link] => http://vimeo.com/73455369
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [artist] => The Orwells
                [track] => In my Bed (live)
                [link] => http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8tA_2qCGnmE
            )
    )
```

But when I pass the array to Twig rendering and tries to output in my template like:

```
<ul>
    {% for song in songs %}
    <li>{{ song.artist }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Nothing happens and I know it's because the array has this top level parent and I can't figure out how to remove it. I've tried several different approaches now. Any idea on how to fix this? FYI, I return my PDO as associative arrays, because Twig doesn't seem to accept objects. Like so:

```
$options = array(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING); // Options for PDO
```

I've even tried some key => value in Twig syntax but no succes. Like so:

```
{% for key in array|keys %}
   ...
{% endfor %}
```

Here's my code getting data from the database:

```
/**
 * Get all songs from database
 */
public function getAllSongs()
{
    $sql = "SELECT id, artist, track, link FROM song";
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();

    return $query->fetchAll();
}
```

Comment: Try going 1 level deeper -> `<ul> {% for songArray in songs %} {% for song in songArray %} <li>{{ song.artist }}</li> {% endfor %} {% endfor %} </ul>`

Comment: Sorry nothing happens, no output at all.

Comment: Have you tried using your associate array -> `<ul> {% for song in songs %} <li>{{ song['artist'] }}</li> {% endfor %} </ul>`

Comment: Still nothing, it's really weird because I thought it was a normal approach to use normal PDO statements and a template library. Other variables like `array('name' => 'Dueify')` works just fine because there's no parent in the array.

Comment: It looks like a valid approach according to the docs -> http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html I am not really familiar with Twig, so not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: Yes, it does. Though I guess I've tried everything by now and it's starting to annoy the hell out of me. Oh well - gotta keep on trying.

Comment: I fixed it, I had to give my array a name so it would recognize it. Like this `$this->loadView('home/index', array('songs' => $songs));` - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it, I had to give my array a name so it would recognize it. From this:

```
$this->loadView('home/index', $songs);
```

To this:

```
$this->loadView('home/index', array('songs' => $songs));
```

And then I could print the data out by writing:

```
<ul>
    {% for song in songs %}
    <li>{{ song.artist }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```